# How to move /var/www/html folder to external hdd?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raspberry-pi

I just setup my own webserver on my raspberry pi. Now I've all php projects inside this folder: `/var/www/html`

Some of this projects are very heavy, what I want do to so, is moving this folder to my external hdd, in particular to this location:

```
/home/pi/hdd/php
```

I'm a newbie to raspberry so I need a bit help. Actually the html folder is empty.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've got three options either create a symbolic link or use a bind-mount, or reconfigure the web server.

- symlink:

  ```
  rmdir /var/www/html
  ln -s /home/pi/hdd/php /var/www/html
  ```

  you may also need to adjust the web server configuration.
- bind mount:

  ```
  mount -o bind /home/pi/hdd/php /var/www/html
  echo /home/pi/hdd/php /var/www/html none bind,user 0 2 >> /etc/fstab
  ```

  this won't work if the hard drive is not mounted first. so you want an entry in `/etc/fstab` that mounts the hard disk before the bind mount is activated.
- reconfigure:

  for apache you'll use the document_root directive to point the new drive

Comment: I'm using apache I think I'll use the second solution, but is possible do the same for mysql databases? thanks

Comment: mysql - much the same as apache except `/var/lib/mysql`  instead of `/var/www/html`,  file permissions may need careful attention.